# How can I skip the Trash when deleting a file?

Tags: macos, external-disk, trash

I frequently connect different external USB hard drives and flash drives to my computer and I would like to facilitate deleting files and regaining disk space from them.

If I simply delete the file, it will be kept in a hidden trash folder on the external drive until I empty the Trash. This also forces me to empty my local trash simultaneously while the external disk is still connected to regain the disk space, which is undesirable.

At the moment, the only other "solution" I've found is moving the file to the internal hard drive and then trash it. This is not optimal because I waste time moving files from one drive to another (I regularly deal with 20GB+ VMs).

**How can I permanently delete a file from an external drive, bypassing the trash?**

Comment: It is very difficult to erase permanently something from a flash based USB drive. Further reading: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5662/is-it-enough-to-only-wipe-a-flash-drive-once

Comment: @Andris Thanks, interesting link. I think I framed my question badly. I'm not interested in a secure deletion. I'm simply interested in deleting a file and regaining the space.

Comment: So, you can't empty trash locally when the file is external, but you can when it's stored internally? Why on earth keep anything in trash anywhere when you are one step away from deleting it? I don't get the justification added. Why not edit that out and just say you want to do X?

Comment: @bmike because I don't mind having a trash locally. I DO mind having a trash on a more limited flash drive. Essentially, deleting a file does not free up space on the drive. I know this is the same for local disks, but it's more acceptable to me. This addresses a specific use case.

Comment: It is incredible that Apple don't see what a problem this is. How on earth is a normal user supposed to understand what is going on? From their point of view their USB drive is empty but useless!

Comment: Just tried to replicate this in El Capitan. It played back the sound file but didn't actually delete the file itself. Couldn't identify anything I left out, though admittedly I'm not very familiar with Automator.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⌫ Delete</kbd> will permanently delete files, with a confirmation dialog warning that this action can not be undone. <kbd>⌘Command</kbd><kbd>⌫ Delete</kbd> simply moves files to Trash, without confirmation.

Tip: whenever you want Mac app to do the same action but a little differently, try doing it with <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> button pressed.

Comment: Thanks! This is now the accepted answer. For the benefit of others, it might be helpful to note in your answer that Alt is called Option on US-layout keyboard.

Answer (score 55):

You can create an Automator service or application to facilitate executing the `rm` shell commando, which will permanently delete files or folders and skip the trash.

For example, start with creating a new Service in **Automator.app**.

- Select `files or folders` as input, you probably also want to limit the availability of this service to the Finder app.

[image: Automator service input]

- Optionally, but highly recommended, first add an `Ask for Confirmation` step to the workflow.

[image: Confirmation step]

- Finally, add the `Run Shell Script` step to the workflow. Make sure to pass input `as arguments`. Then you can put in the following script:

  ```
  for f in "$@"
  do
      rm -rf "$f"
  done
  ```

[image: Input shell script]

As mentioned by @Thecafremo, you can also add a `-P` parameter to `rm` for additional security while deleting. For an extra nicety, you can add some audible feedback by adding the following command at the end of the shell script:

```
afplay "/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/finder/empty trash.aif"
```

Save your service, and it should be ready to use in Finder from the Services menu in the menu bar. The service will also appear at the bottom of the menu you get by right clicking on files in Finder, although to make it appear there you may have to run it once from the `Finder > Services` menu first.  You can also configure a keyboard shortcut to your service in the Keyboard preference pane of System Preferences.

[image: Services menu]

[image: Service in action]

Instead of creating a service, you could similarly create an application in Automator, which you can pin in the Dock so you can drag files to it.

Comment: This is for sure the most elegant solution. And it's free :-)

Comment: This is really nice. Thanks for a great solution :)

Comment: This isn't working for me in Mavericks... It just doesn't do anything when I use the service.

Comment: Great answer, but consider improving it by making it prompt for password if and when superuser privilege is necessary for a deletion.

Comment: I would like to add that this service can even be used to delete files that are already in the trash--something that is otherwise very difficult. (Awesome!)

Comment: Bravo and +1 for this answer. I also assigned it a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences. I **wanted** Opt+Del but the delete key was not assignable. I went the `Cmd+Opt+Ctrl+\ `. I have a 101 Apple keyboard and long thumbs!

Comment: Awesome! Couple of things. Clicking on the icon inside Ask for Confirmation step will change it to an yellow exclamation sign - handy to warn that what you're about to do is dangerous. When saving, the name entered should be "Permanently Delete" as this is what will be shown in the Services menu. Sadly this doesn't support `sudo` when password is required. I tried using `osascript -e ... with administrator priveleges` but escaping the original `"` with `\"` didn't seem to work.

Comment: **Problem:** If I select one single folder, the Services menu shows "No services apply". I can only see the service when I select two or more folders, a file or a mixture of files, folders or both. Why is that, and what is the solution?

Answer (score 22):

And option could be Terminal command `rm`, with the `-P` option if you want some added security:

> [Option **-P** will] 
>   Overwrite regular files before deleting them.  Files are overwritten three times, first with the byte pattern 0xff, then 0x00, and then 0xff again, before they are deleted.

To do so, just:

1. Open the **Terminal.app** (Found in /Applications/Utilities).
2. Type `rm -P`  and drag the file to the terminal window. Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Woah, dragging the folder will delete the whole folder, right?

Comment: @duci9y Right! I'll edit the answer to correct it. Answering without proofreading is not the best thing to do, indeed.

Comment: You can also remove a folder if you use the option `-rf`.

Comment: sudo rm -rf followed by space works wonders, thanks!

Comment: The Accepted Solution above is good if you have to do this frequently, but I just had one file I needed to nuke (from orbit) and this does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Have you consider to use [Trash Without](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/trash-without/id547583082?mt=12) from the Mac App Store?

Comment: This looks decent, but I was wondering if there's anything freely available.

Comment: That's true :-) But at least it is cheap.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like [Trash X](http://www.northernsoftworks.com/trashx.html). The description says:

> You can use it to instantly delete or shred file and folders without
>   sending them to the trash. You can use it to empty or shred trash only
>   on selected disks. And of course, you can use it just like the
>   trashcan you've always had on your desktop.

Answer (score 4):

The following trick works with OS X El Capitan. I got the tip from [here](http://www.igeeksblog.com/delete-files-permanently-on-el-capitan/).

Select your file(s) in Finder. Go to the `File` menu, and when you press the `alt/option` key, you will see the "Move to Trash" option change to "Delete Immediately...".

Answer (score 2):

Background information can be found in the paper [Secure Deletion of Data from Magnetic and Solid-State Memory](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/secure_del.html)

An implementation of the knowledge gained from this paper is [GNU shred](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shred-invocation.html). This tool can be installed as part of [`coreutils`](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/coreutils/Portfile) from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/ports.php).

Comment: Why the downvote? Who doesn't like MacPorts or GNU tools?

Comment: I wasn't the person to down vote, but I don't feel that this answers the question. Perhaps the original is worded badly

Answer (score 2):

There is a **free** tool called *Skip The Trash*, which not only allows regular deletion, but authenticated deletion as an admin. It adds context menus to the Finder:

http://www.blazingtools.com/delete_without_trash_mac.html

Answer (score 0):

As of El Capitan 10.11.6 this is now possible without using Terminal.app: select the files you want rid of, right click and pick "Delete Immediately…".