# .Trashes folder on USB won't delete

Tags: usb

I am trying to delete files off my 8GB USB Cruzer device, as I often put movies on it to watch on my PS3. When I plug it into my PC, I can delete files off it fine, but when I plus it into my Macbook Pro, it creates a .Trashes folder. When I put the files I want to delete into the trash bin, it goes into this .Trashes folder, but when I try to empty the .Trashes folder, a window comes up saying "Moving "Trash" to "Trash" and it just stays on that window, it does not delete. I waited for an hour and still nothing. I have tried restarting but it still does not work. I do not want to go upstairs to my PC everytime I need to delete files.

Comment: If anyone came here looking for an answer because the `.Trashes` folder stayed even after emptying the trash, try the `rm` method mentioned in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87397/197118)

Comment: If an answer below answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

The '.Trashes' folder is for OS X to remember that you moved files to the Trash but haven't deleted it. To remove the files from the '.Trashes' folder you need to empty the trash.

You can empty the trash by right clicking on the trash can in your dock and selecting 'Empty Trash'.

Comment: Shocking that Apple make it work like this. 99% of users will have no idea what is going on. Their USB drive is empty but useless!

Answer (score 5):

To avoid having to go via Trash you can do the following

- Open Terminal (in `/Applications/Utilities` or via Spotlight)
- Type `rm` followed by a <kbd>Space</kbd> (or, if you want to delete whole folders that way, type `rm -r` followed by <kbd>Space</kbd>)
- Drag all the files you want to delete from Finder into the Terminal window (release the mouse after the green + appears)
- Press <kbd>Return</kbd>

Comment: Or, check this related answer :) http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66369/how-can-i-skip-the-trash-when-deleting-a-file/66379#66379

Comment: This can pose problems if users try dragging in folders

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by simply emptying the trash on my computer.

The .Trashes folder also emptied on my pen drive, in doing so.

Hope this works for others.

R

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is this but I found a solution:
- edit the 1 file and corrupt it (it's a code delete the middle line)
- save
- then delete the .Trash folder and the 1 file
they will not come again

Answer (score 0):

I plug my USB into a PC/laptop running Windows (you may have to click on View all Files) it will come up, highlight and delete.

Comment: ha! So much easier but...on a mac?